# Using ion range slider to store values in local storage to output in html element

Tags: javascript, html

I am using ion range slider as part of a web app to re create the iphone alarm creation process.

I have three screens where the first screen I add a new alarm and the second alarm screen has two range sliders where the user can scroll for the hour and minutes. I've managed to use a function from ion slider where the hours get outputted into console log however I am unable to get it to show in my html element where the hour and minutes are displayed.

I want to take the two values (hour and minutes) and then add it on to the first screen with the rest of the values (append to a new div like how the other alarms that are set)

[Alarm screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eOxz.png)

Here is a codepen of my code so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQRqyV

My function for outputting the values for range slider along with the parameters as suggested by the documentation:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#alarmHours').ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 0,
    max: 12,
    step: 1,
    grid: true,
    grid_num: 5,
    grid_snap: true,

    onChange: function(data) {
        console.log(data.from);
        // document.getElementById("test-hour").setAttribute(data, 
      from);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you just want to display slider values in `div` element?

Comment: I want to display it in a p element on the second screen but also add it on the row in another page. For example in the screenshot of the pages, second screen the user will input the hours and minutes with the slider which gets outputted on the second screen in  p elements for the hours and minutes. When  the user goes back to the first screen; even on refresh the same values should be present in a new row. Hope that’s clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the append function to add the values to the table once a button is clicked. This allows me to add the values in a new div and stack it on the table.